# Connecting talend with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, talend, talend-mdm

I see on product description of talend MDM free version that it supports connectivity with Hadoop however do not see any option on the interface.

I need to get the data from S3 and connect it with Talend. Can you please suggest if this can be done or not. If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1):

You should use tJDBCConnection component to connect to Hadoop and tJDBCOutput to load data there.

[image: Screen with location of JDBC components plus sample of my job where I'm doing similar things as requested in comment below]

Comment: can u pls share a screenshot of where u see this option. I cannot find this in Open Source MDM Talend @voystin

Comment: @Vaibhav check my answer - i put the screen there.